# Oracle Db to PostgreSQL conversion using ora2pg

Tags: oracle, postgresql, ora2pg

I am trying to migrate my Oracle database to PostgreSQL using Ora2pg tool.
Exported DDL file successfully, but when I am trying to import the same into PostgreSQL server getting some errors as below.

There is a check constraint in Oracle as IS JSON condition, when I exported from Ora2PG it is generated as

```
 ALTER TABLE Temp_table ADD CONSTRAINT ensure_json1 CHECK (rpdata IS JSON);
```

When I try to execute the same in PostgreSQL server, getting "Syntax error at or near JSON".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this in Postgres.

Postgres has a native JSON datatype that validates JSON automatically. In Oracle you need that check constraint, to "turn" a CLOB into a JSON column (without it, the values aren't validated and certain JSON operations don't work)

Just remove that constraint from your Postgres script (assuming the column is indeed defined as `json` or ideally `jsonb`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the column created in the above Alter is Varchar(4000) in oracle.

Comment: @Kiran: then make it a `jsonb` in Postgres